# how to put expand icon in notification in android

Tags: android

i'm trying to put expand icon in notification on my developing app. I already done notification `RemortView` collapse and expand Layout helping with [this site](http://www.brevitysoftware.com/blog/different-types-of-notification-android/).Below pitcher is my current status of my notification.

[image]

My Code given below:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);
        builder.setTicker(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.custom_notification));
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small_basket);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        builder.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
        builder.setCustomContentView(contentView);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Actual my need is **how to put expand icon and how to get that clicking event from notification `RemortView`** using for expand and collapse the notification.

Look like below pitcher.
This pitcher is just a example for that expand icon.

[image]
please assist me.

Comment: I would start here https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html then learn how to request a view object when you click a button do search "android onClick get View" it might open up a new world

Comment: Hi @Grendel, please see my updated question.

Comment: here is a link that might help http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-broadcast-receiver-example/

Comment: one more and would you tell me what a RemortView is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629613/notification-for-low-battery

Comment: Dear @Grendel please understand my question. I'm not asking about battery information, That pitcher just an example. I'm clearly asking about that expand icon in notification (Clearly marked in pitcher).

Comment: OK pleas explain expanded icon! Do you want to know how to make an icon bigger or put some text beside the icon Or do you want to click an Icon and bake something happen So as of now you have the icon and the text? You need to understand most people here do not read pictures and know what to do THEY READ CODE post your code please

Comment: @Grendel really sorry. can you see my new update question please.

Comment: Hi @GowsikRaja did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its an old question, but for the sake of the nature of Stack Overflow, I'll give you a proper answer.

Instead of implementing your own header including an arrow to expand/collapse the notification, you might want to decorate your custom notifiction with Androids default header.

The only thing you should take care about is to use the builder methods in the proper order to accomplish your task.Fist you have to set the remote views for collapsed and expanded RemoteViews (what you call `RemortViews`), and THEN you wrap the `NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle` around it.

```
notificationBuilder.setCustomContentView(contentView)
    .setCustomBigContentView(expandedView)
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()) // <- That's what you want
val notification = notificationBuilder.build()
```

Do not forget to delete your custom header stuff as it does not make sense anymore.

[Click here for the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's useful for others.

Comment: Without using DecoratedCustomViewStyle() or setStyle, how to achieve it

Answer (score -1):

OK now that we have code I tried this and it worked for me you will need to do some adjustments on where and what is stored

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    android.app.NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (android.app.NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: My humble request to you, Please read the question fully and then put your answer. I already done your given solution, also mentioned in my question. I know it's working fine. My need is **How to put expand icon in notification**. It's also marked in second pitcher.

Comment: @GowsikRaja What or which one is the expanded icon ? And did you replace your code with mine ? Is the RED part the expanded icon or the BLACK part ? We are having trouble understanding what you want! Two icons Also note my code is different than yours

Comment: Yes, In your code **setLargeIcon**  is a extra thing.That's also i done by using RemortView. Did you see expand icon near **Android System** text in 2nd pitcher on my question. I'm asking about that icon.

Comment: @GowsikRaja Did you try my code ? Is the red part  or the black part the expanded code ? So if you want two icons have you tried asking for two icons in your code the notification builder needs to know you want two icons SO here is a thought TELL it to fetch another icon

Comment: @GowsikRaja I am not sure but I think the photo you are showing is an app that might have been built with a Scroll View or a Frame Layout You might do a little reading